# VideoView taking correct space but video not showing up on complete area

Tags: java, android, xml, android-videoview, aspect-ratio

I am using VideoView and TextView side by side, and both the widgets are taking correct space which i have given to use, but the issue is video is not showing as big it should be.

**activity_main.xml:-**

```
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/video_frame"
                android:layout_width="690dp"
                android:layout_height="300dp">  

                   <VideoView
                       android:id="@+id/VideoView"
                       android:layout_width="fill_parent"             
                       android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

                ;;;;;;;;;;
            </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Here you have applied `android:layout_weight="2"` for `LinearLayout` so just set its `width` as `0` instead of `fill_parent`.

Comment: @X'Factor you mean instead of match_parent

Comment: @X'Factor tried even not showing that complete linearlayout in which i have these two widgets (videoview and textview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No worries just an **Aspect Ratio** issue, no one can do anything in that

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I guess you problem is in the complex layout architecture (`FrameLayout` in a vertical `LinearLayout` in a horizontal one that is in another horizontal one and all this is placed in another horizontal `LinearLayout`. Why don't you use a single `RelativeLayout`? It provides a convenient way to align the views according to the parent borders and other components?